# How is the step execution context loaded from RDBMS batch metadata tables on restarting?

Tags: spring-batch

I understand that step execution context is loaded into an in-memory map then to `batch_step_execution_context`  table's `short_context` column and when the job is restarted, the same in-memory map execution context is loaded automatically for us for the restarted job. But, when the restart is triggered after the in-memory map is wiped-off(eg: application restart), I got to know it is loaded from batch metadata RDBMS tables(precisely, `batch_step_execution_context` table). My question is - as the column length is 2500, spring batch truncates the data and adds an ellipses to the content, what if the data I put is more then 2500 characters? How is it able to load the original data(not the truncated with ellipses one)?

PS: I use this step execution context to pass my intended partition's identifiers to my readers as shown in most of the examples.

Please help me understand how this is taken care in the framework.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful observation, I found that the Spring Batch is intelligent enough to put the full content into `serialized_context` column of the `batch_step_execution_context` table if the content length is more then 2500 characters. In case the in-memory maps are cleared, they get restored from either of `short_context` or `serialized_context` columns.

Answer (score 1):

The execution context is deserialized first from the full version of the context, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/83579cfbdfbf79d9454a1cc83f49a644c3ce68c0/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcExecutionContextDao.java#L319-L322). Restart meta-data of your partitioned step should be saved/loaded automatically by default if you use a persistent job repository and restart the same job instance.

Comment: What if my short_context is truncated while writing to DB(asking as I see an ellipses to the content if it is more than 2500 characters)? How does it restore in that case?
Also, can you point a reference on how to use persistent job repository(I am using postgres, is it the similar that you are talking?)

Comment: You can increase the column size in the DDL script and set [JobRepositoryFactoryBean#setMaxVarCharLength](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setMaxVarCharLength-int-) to the same value.